# Xcode "build failed" issue with all codes?

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I can't open any project/code all of them given me issues
xcode 7.1.1 7b

examples for the issues
"FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h file not found"
'RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h file not found'

(this steps didn't work with me
    Go to Build Phases in your Project Target.
    In Link Binary With Libraries, click the "+" button.
    Click on "Add Other..." button
    Browse your FacebookSDK folder. Generally in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/
    Clik on (select) "facebookSDK.framework" and then OPEN.)

Comment: What part of it "didn't work"? You're giving a lot of steps but not saying what fails, just that _something_ fails _somewhere_.

Comment: I followed the steps and add the facebook sdk ok! then clicked clean = fine but when I click "build" it's appear the same error "file not found"

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson are you still there?